# iOS 8 - External Accessory picker is collapsed, empty

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios8, external-accessory

I have an issue with the External Accessory framework in iOS 8. The `EAAccessoryManager` has the following function: `showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:completion:` which displayed the following dialog on iOS 7:

[image: External accessory dialog in iOS 7]

But in iOS 8, the dialog is as follows:

[image: External accessory dialog in iOS 8]

I have no clue where this issue lies. I have added the following two values to my `info.plist`, but with no success:

- `NSBluetoothUsageDescription`
- `Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description`

Is there a way to open up the accessory dialog? Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what about an normal issue because iOS8 is still in beta?

Comment: I have submitted this issue through the bug reporter on iOS 8. iOS 7 works fine. I thought maybe I missed something. We will see what Apple says about this through the bug reporter.

Comment: Nope! Don't have any update yet.. Still the same